# How to create a new SeednKey.dll which in turn refers to already existing .dll files

Tags: security, dll, capl, canoe

Use case: Canoe application accepts only one SeednKey.dll configuration in its panel configuration.
Vector supports ask me to create a new SeednKey.dll files which refers to my two main .dll files

Do anyone knows how to do this?

If yes, please share your information. Its highly appreciated

Canoe Seedkey.dll creation referring two other .dll files

Comment: The question is a bit broad to answer. How to create a SeedNKey dll is described in CANoe's documentation. If your dll needs to call into another dll, that would be a simple call between to libraries. What excatly is your problem?